# Orientation Problem with more Views and Controller (iPad)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, orientation

Im writing an App for iPad using Orientation.
The App-Delegate.h has a window, an UIViewController, an UINavigationController and an UITabbarController:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet LoginRVC *loginRVC;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet ChooseCameraRVC *chooseCameraRVC;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *hauptRVC;
```

Every Controller uses the "shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation"-method to autorotate itself.

i change the views using:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
```

and then

```
[loginRVC.view removeFromSuperview];
[_window addSubview:chooseCameraRVC.view];
```

and the other way around too, ofc.

So my problem is, when i am in the second view (chooseCameraRVC) and switch the orientation, then go back to my first view, its not rotated. It do autorotate but after the animation is completed.

I tried many things like calling "shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation"-method of all views, not removing the views from window ... but no success til now.

Is this maybe a "feature" of the simulator? (i hope not).

Pls help me.
Sharky

---

Ok. I prepared my source code to be presented here.

Note: I didn't copy the methods which only has [super ...] within or are completely commented out.

At first the AppDelegate.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ChooseCameraRVC.h"
#import "LoginRVC.h"

@interface NetCoWatchAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet LoginRVC *loginRVC;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet ChooseCameraRVC *chooseCameraRVC;

-(void)changeView:(id)sender:(BOOL)direction;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
#import "NetCoWatchAppDelegate.h"
#import "LoginRVC.h"
#import "ChooseCameraRVC.h"
#import "ChooseCameraVC.h"

@implementation NetCoWatchAppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize loginRVC, chooseCameraRVC;

-(void)changeView:(id)sender:(BOOL)direction{ 
    //configure animation
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
    if(sender == loginRVC){ //sender is LoginView 
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:_window cache:YES];
        [loginRVC.view removeFromSuperview];
        [_window addSubview:chooseCameraRVC.view];
    }else if(sender == chooseCameraRVC){ 
        [chooseCameraRVC.view removeFromSuperview];
        if(!direction){  //FlipFromRight = YES, ...left = NO
            [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:_window cache:YES];        
            [_window addSubview:loginRVC.view];
        }   

    }else if([sender class] == [ChooseCameraVC class]){
        [chooseCameraRVC.view removeFromSuperview];
        if(!direction){ //Camera gewählt //FlipFromRight = YES, ...left = NO
            [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:_window cache:YES];
            [_window addSubview:loginRVC.view];
        }

    }else { //default solution
        UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Bad Value" message:[[sender class] description] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [av show];
        [av release];
    }
    [UIView commitAnimations]; //start animation
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    // Add the navigation controller's view to the window and display.
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_window release];
    [loginRVC release];
    [chooseCameraRVC release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

The LoginRVC.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface LoginRVC : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>{
    NSMutableArray *usernameArray;
    NSMutableArray *passwordArray;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *usernameTF;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *passwordTF;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *loginBn;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISwitch *saveUsernameSwitch;

-(IBAction)tryLogin:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)closeKeyboard:(id)sender;

@end
```

The LoginRVC.m:

```
#import "LoginRVC.h"
#import "NetCoWatchAppDelegate.h"

@implementation LoginRVC

@synthesize usernameTF, passwordTF, loginBn, saveUsernameSwitch;

-(IBAction)tryLogin:(id)sender{
    //login successful if the textfields are euqal with an existing account
#warning Access the data base and search for the account.
    bool accountFound = NO;
    for (int i=0; i<usernameArray.count; i++) {
        if([[usernameArray objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:usernameTF.text] 
           && [[passwordArray objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:passwordTF.text]){
            accountFound = YES;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(accountFound)
    { //login successful - now change the values and then the view
        if(![saveUsernameSwitch isOn])
            usernameTF.text = @"";
        passwordTF.text = @"";
        NetCoWatchAppDelegate *main = (NetCoWatchAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [main changeView:self:YES];
    }else{ //login failt - show a popup window for the user
        UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login fehlgeschlagen" message:@"Username oder Passwort falsch!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [av show];
        [av release];
    }
}

-(IBAction)closeKeyboard:(id)sender{
    if([passwordTF isFirstResponder])
        [passwordTF resignFirstResponder];
    else
        [usernameTF resignFirstResponder];
}

// this helps dismiss the keyboard then the "done" button is clicked
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if(textField == usernameTF){ //move to password textfield
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        [passwordTF becomeFirstResponder];
    }else if(textField == passwordTF){ //textField == passwordTF -> try to login
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        [self tryLogin:self];
    }
    return YES;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization    
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.textFieldRounded.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;    // no auto correction support
#warning Define right keyboard type.
    usernameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"dkoehn", @"bmazanek", @"sbehne", @"mballhausen", @"efiedler", @"bbraasch", @"azuber", @"tstolt", nil];
    passwordArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"test1",@"test2",@"test3",@"test4",@"test5",@"test6",@"test7",@"test8", nil];

//    usernameTF.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress;

    [usernameTF becomeFirstResponder]; //get first focus when the app stars
    //set return key on the keyboard and the delegate for an action
    usernameTF.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;  // type of the return key
    passwordTF.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyGo;
    //set delegate to connect with a method "-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField"
    usernameTF.delegate = self;
    passwordTF.delegate = self;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{    
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}

@end
```

The ChooseCameraRVC.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ChooseCameraRVC : UINavigationController <UINavigationControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *zurueckBN;

-(IBAction)exitToLoginView:(id)sender;

@end
```

The ChooseCameraRVC.m:

```
#import "ChooseCameraRVC.h"
#import "NetCoWatchAppDelegate.h"
#import "ChooseCameraCell.h"

@implementation ChooseCameraRVC

@synthesize zurueckBN;

-(IBAction)exitToLoginView:(id)sender{
#warning Eventually logout the User.

    //change the view
    [((NetCoWatchAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]) changeView:self:NO];
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{    
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}

@end
```

ChooseCameraVC.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ChooseCameraVC : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate>

@end
```

and the ChooseCameraVC.m:

```
#import "ChooseCameraVC.h"
#import "ChooseCameraCell.h"
#import "NetCoWatchAppDelegate.h"

@implementation ChooseCameraVC

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
} 

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Customize the number of sections if grouped. 
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
#warning Get count of cameras out of the data base.
    return 5;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Camera";
    return cell;
}    

@end
```

I hope u can find the problem.

Greetings. $h@rky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

now i found my mistake. as u can see i have the views as variables in the app delegate. so if the second view changes the orientation, the other ones didn't know a thing about it. if the view now changes the "new" one recognizes the orientation change AFTER the animation, so while the animation is running, the "new" view has the wrong orientation.

So if u want to switch a view, just create a new one because it gets initialized with the right orientation.

kind regards
$h@rky

Answer (score 0):

For support all orientations your viewcontroller should implement `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` like this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

Every viewcontroller should implement this method for support required orientations.

Check also `Supported interface orientations` item in `.plist` file. Maybe you have wrong parameters.

Comment: all done before. its working really fine if u watch the view itself. but if u change the orientation and switch to another view, then it autorotate AFTER the animation and this looks pretty bad.

Comment: Hm, try to make animation with blocks: `[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4f animations:^{ _myView.frame = fullRect; } ];`

Comment: I don't have more thoughts cos i see only bit of your code. There are many reasons for this unspecified behavior.

Comment: e.g.? 
What do u want to see. The rest of the code is logic and hasn't got much to do with the UI (in my opinion).

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `secondviewcontroller`

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
UIViewController *controller = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
[controller shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];

return YES;
}
```

Hope it works..!!:)

Comment: nope it doesn't. the first view is just an UIView inside the UIViewController, so not connected with the second. Maybe thats the Problem!?!